# Proving a proposition of list L ++ [] ≡ L

Tags: agda

Using the agda standard library (v13)

How can I fill the next hole?

```
$ cat foo.aga
open import Data.List using
  ( List ; [] ; _∷_ ; _++_ ; [_] )
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
  using ( _≡_; refl; cong; trans; sym)

p : ∀ {A : Set} {L : List A} → L ++ [] ≡ L
p = {!!}
```

baby steps:

```
p0 : (x : Prop) → ([ x ]) ++ [] ≡ [ x ]
p0 = λ x → refl

p1 : (x y : Prop) → (x ∷ y ∷ []) ++ [] ≡ x ∷ y ∷ []
p1 = λ x y → refl
```

In the hole why doesn't work refl? is it due by the structural recursion of ∷ on the first argument?

I think that doing some recursion I can prove p looking at p0 and p1, but at this moment, I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is pattern match on the implicit argument `{L}`, so that you can define `p` case-by-case for empty and cons lists:

```
p : ∀ {A : Set} {L : List A} → L ++ [] ≡ L
p {L = []} = ?
p {L = x ∷ L} = ?
```

The type of the first hole is

```
Goal: [] ≡ []
```

which you should be able to prove easily.

The type of the second hole is

```
Goal: x ∷ L ++ [] ≡ x ∷ L
```

By recursively calling `p` on the now-smaller `L`, we can rewrite that goal (since `p {L = L}` proves `L ++ [] ≡ L`, we can replace the `L ++ []` on the left-hand side with just `L`):

```
p : ∀ {A : Set} {L : List A} → L ++ [] ≡ L
p {L = []} = ?
p {L = x ∷ L} rewrite p {L = L} = ?
```

giving

```
Goal: x ∷ L ≡ x ∷ L
```

Let me know in a comment if you need any further help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to see how `_++_` is defined. Using the definition here: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/repos/lib/src/Data/List.agda Agda is able to conclude `refl` is applicable to `p0`.

In the case for `p0` it is easy to see that `[ x ] == x :: []` by definition of `[_]`, then `(x :: []) ++ [] == x :: ([] ++ [])` by one case of `_++_`, and `[] ++ [] == []` by the second case of `_++_`.

The case `p1` already requires reasoning by induction, and since in the end you will need a proof by induction anyway, you do not gain anything by proving `p1` on its own.

The case `p` has an unknown nesting of `List` constructors, `_::_` and `[]`, and a non-trivial application of cases from `_++_`.

In order to construct proof by induction for this problem, you need to see how to apply `cong` to prove statements about longer lists from statements about shorter lists.